# best way of initializing firebase database and auth in Java Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am confused about how to initialize Firebase auth and database. Is it to make a singleton and use it across every activity or initialize it for every call-in activity?

I often go to initializing every activity. Can you help me guys to have an insight on what is the best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to creating a new instance of the [FirebaseAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth) and [FirebaseDatabase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase) classes, then in both cases, you should call the `getInstance()` method. Besides that, you'll always have a single instance because both are singleton. There is no need to create another one. There is no problem in calling them in multiple activities.